# Property Survey Pins and Shifting Terrain

Tags: landscaping

My neighbor helped me locate my iron property/survey pins with an industrial magnetic locator, and two of the pins were pretty much 6-8 inches below grade, but the other two were at least 12+ inches down. The pin that was the deepest was located on a very steep sloped hill, and almost buried under an old growth tree.

The original survey was done in the mid-1950's, so how much movement due to natural forces could there be in regard to an old boundary marker? Specifically the one buried the deepest?

Comment: Contact the planning department - they would likely know the ranges of movement and what they consider.

Comment: Any chance the grade was raised?

Comment: Hard to say, and I was just curious because I've heard builders talk about "slope creep" and "soil creep" messing with concrete walls and fence lines. And the fact that this particular property pin was located at twice the depth of the other property pins. And it is halfway down a very steep hillside.

Comment: during orienteering activities in boy scouts, they told us that markers could wander 1"/year. I have no idea if that's accurate, but they were right about other things.

Answer (score 1):

With vegetation growth, time, soil movement (to what degree unknown), human disturbance, etc., there is most likely no answer to your question, only opinions.

If you need to know to determine a boundary, you will need another survey.

The surveys are done using a beginning point that is known to be accurate.
The iron pins are not accurate over time so they would not be used as a starting point. Thus should not be used to give a legal opinion of a boundary...only a guess.